# How to perform a range on a Theano's TensorVariable?

Tags: python, theano

How to perform a range on a Theano's TensorVariable?

Example:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function

constant = T.dscalar('constant')
n_iters = T.dscalar('n_iters')
start = T.dscalar('start')
result = start  

for iter in range(n_iters):
    result = start + constant

f = function([start, constant, n_iters], result)
print('f(0,2,5): {0}'.format(f(1,2)))
```

returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_theano.py", line 9, in <module>
    for iter in range(n_iters):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got TensorVariable.
```

What is the correct way to use a range on a Theano's TensorVariable?

Comment: reading about theano.scan will probably be helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not clear what this code is attempting to do because even if the loop worked, it wouldn't compute anything useful: `result` will always equal the sum of `start` and `constant` irrespective of the number of iterations.

I'll assume that the intention was to compute `result` like this:

```
for iter in range(n_iters):
    result = result + constant
```

The problem is that you're mixing symbolic, delayed execution, Theano operations with non-symbolic, immediately executed, Python operations.

`range` is a Python function that expects a Python integer parameter but you're providing a Theano symbolic value (`n_iters`, which has a double type instead of an integer type but let's assume it's actually an `iscalar` instead of a `dscalar`). As far as Python is concerned all Theano symbolic tensors are just objects: instances of a class type somewhere within the Theano library; they are most assuredly not integers. Even if you squint and try to pretend a Theano `iscalar` looks like a Python integer, it still doesn't work because Python operations execute immediately which means `n_iters` needs to have a value immediately. Theano on the other hand doesn't have a value for any `iscalar` until one is provided by calling a compiled Theano function (or via `eval`).

To create a symbolic range, you can use `theano.tensor.arange` which operates just like NumPy's [`arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), but symbolically.

Example:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function

my_range_max = T.iscalar('my_range_max')
my_range = T.arange(my_range_max)

f = function([my_range_max], my_range)
print('f(10): {0}'.format(f(10)))
```

outputs:

```
f(10): [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

By making `n_iters` a symbolic variable you are implicitly saying "I don't know how many iterations there need to be in this loop until a value is provided for `n_iters` later". That being the case, you must use a symbolic loop instead of a Python `for` loop. In the latter case you must tell Python how many times to iterate *now*, you can't delay that decision until a value is provided for `n_iters` later. To solve this you need to switch to a symbolic loop, which is provided by Theano's [`scan`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html) operator.

Here's the code changed to use `scan` (as well as the other assumed changes).

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function

constant = T.dscalar('constant')
n_iters = T.iscalar('n_iters')
start = T.dscalar('start')

results, _ = theano.scan(lambda result, constant: result + constant,
                         outputs_info=[start], non_sequences=[constant], n_steps=n_iters)

f = function([start, constant, n_iters], results[-1])
print('f(0,2,5): {0}'.format(f(0, 2, 5)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very clear and thorough explanation! I'm surprised I cannot see `theano.tensor.arange()` in the documentation (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html) except in one example (at the beginning of the [section on indexing](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#indexing)).